# C++ REST (Casablanca) - web::json::value has no member named 'field_map'

Tags: c++, json, visual-studio-2015, getjson, casablanca

I am new to C++ REST ('Casablanca'). I read the tutorial [here](http://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2013/08/19/full-fledged-client-server-example-with-cpprest-sdk-110/). After than, I took a sample code from there and tried to run it on my machine.

**Below is the code**

```
std::map<utility::string_t, utility::string_t> dictionary;

void handle_get(http_request request)
{
    TRACE(L"\nhandle GET\n");

    web::json::value::field_map answer;

    for (auto const & p : dictionary)
    {
        answer.push_back(std::make_pair(json::value(p.first), json::value(p.second)));
    }

    request.reply(status_codes::OK, json::value::object(answer));
}

int main()
{
    http_listener listener(L"http://127.0.0.1:8080/stockData");

    listener.support(methods::GET, handle_get);

    return 0;
}
```

In this code, I am **getting error as below**

[image]

I checked the header file `json.h` and could not find a member (class/struct) named `field_map`
**Please help**

Comment: The tutorial is from 2013. So. When was your version of the library released?

Comment: @underscore_d I have taken library from NuGet version CPP REST 140 v2.8.0 and I am using VS 2015

Comment: Do you expect me to go and look up when that version was released, or can you just look at the copy you already have (e.g. the timestamps, changelog, etc.) and tell us?

Comment: @underscore_d Sorry, Nov 23, 2015

Comment: Thanks. Well, because your version is newer, perhaps the member `field_map` has been deprecated and removed since that tutorial was written. If so, you will simply need to consult the newer documentation and see whether there are any notes about a replacement or some other way to do the same thing, or search for discussions where others might've talked about the removal and how to adjust for it.

Comment: @underscore_d Hmm... Thanks, I will try to search for the alternative.. though no luck so far..

Answer (score 6):

I think below code can replace your code and should be compile latest stable version cpprestsdk v2.8.0

```
std::map<utility::string_t, utility::string_t> dictionary;

void handle_get(http_request request)
{
    TRACE(L"\nhandle GET\n");

    json::value obj;
    for ( auto const & p : dictionary )
    {
        obj[p.first] = json::value::string(p.second);
    }

    // this is just for debugging
    utility::stringstream_t stream;
    obj.serialize(stream);
    std::wcout << stream.str();

    request.reply( status_codes::OK, obj);
}
```

Comment: Awesome ! I just did not get this idea